# Android OutOfMemory Issue

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, imageview, scale

i face outofmemory issue in my app 
and after some search, I found out this code

```
    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

but IDK how to use it , any help please ?
and is the code right ?

Comment: what are you trying to do that you are getting this error? just posing code that you found without any description about the problem really does not help

Comment: Can you post the entire exception/logcat error message and the line at which it occurs?

Comment: the error caused by the big size photo , and this code reduces the photo size .. but IDK how to use it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but IDK how to use it

Then I guess you haven't implemented it!
Well, that method will convert a file of yours (saved at SD card, eg) to a resized Bitmap wich can be used as background of an ImageView.

Now, answering to your question, you can use it as I show you below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File(your_string_file_path));
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

That's all you have to know, I guess.