# Android: BitmapFactory.decodeStream() out of memory with a 400KB file with 2MB free heap

Tags: android, heap-memory

My app is hitting an OOM error at the following line in the source:

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(imgFilename));
```

Just before the allocation that causes the app to be killed with an OOM error:

```
(...)
08-05 21:22:12.443: I/dalvikvm-heap(2319): Clamp target GC heap from 25.056MB to 24.000MB
08-05 21:22:12.443: D/dalvikvm(2319): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 2709K/5379K, external 18296K/19336K, paused 58ms
08-05 21:22:14.513: D/dalvikvm(2319): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 2709K/5379K, external 18296K/19336K, paused 101ms
08-05 21:22:14.903: I/dalvikvm-heap(2319): Clamp target GC heap from 25.073MB to 24.000MB
08-05 21:22:14.903: D/dalvikvm(2319): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 50% free 2709K/5379K, external 18312K/19336K, paused 53ms
08-05 21:22:22.843: D/ddm-heap(2319): Heap GC request
08-05 21:22:22.963: I/dalvikvm-heap(2319): Clamp target GC heap from 25.073MB to 24.000MB
08-05 21:22:22.963: D/dalvikvm(2319): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
08-05 21:22:22.963: D/dalvikvm(2319): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 50% free 2710K/5379K, external 18312K/19336K, paused 116ms
```

DDMS reports a similar picture about the state of the heap:

```
Heap Size:  5.254 MB
Allocated:  2.647 MB
Free:   2.607 MB
%Used:  50.38%
#Objects    49,028
```

Single stepping over this line results in an OOM error:

```
08-05 21:26:04.783: D/dalvikvm(2319): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 2710K/5379K, external 18312K/19336K, paused 57ms
08-05 21:26:05.023: E/dalvikvm-heap(2319): 2097152-byte external allocation too large for this process.
08-05 21:26:05.163: I/dalvikvm-heap(2319): Clamp target GC heap from 25.073MB to 24.000MB
08-05 21:26:05.163: E/GraphicsJNI(2319): VM won't let us allocate 2097152 bytes
08-05 21:26:05.163: D/dalvikvm(2319): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 50% free 2710K/5379K, external 18312K/19336K, paused 30ms
08-05 21:26:05.283: D/skia(2319): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

1. The size of the file referenced by "imgFileName" is reported to be < 400K on Windows. So why does BitmapFactory.decodeStream try to allocate 2MB?
2. Why is there an OOM error when there seems to be enough free space?

This app is targeting Android 2.2 and up.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Android library is not so smart for loading images, so you have to create workarounds for this.

In my tests, `Drawable.createFromStream` uses more memory than `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`.

You may change the Color scheme to reduce memory (RGB_565), but the image will lose quality too:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

You can also load a scaled image, which will decrease a lot the memory usage, but you have to know your images to not lose too much quality of it.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

To define the inSampleSize dynamically, you may want to know the image size to take your decision:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
// recreate the stream
// make some calculation to define inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = ?;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
```

You can customize the inSampleSize according to the screen size of the device. To get the screen size, you can do:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity) activity).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Other tutorials:

- http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: How can one calculate image size to calculate inSampleSize dynamically?

Comment: I have edited the question including the answer of your question!

Comment: Screen size is not image size. I have an application that lets a user take or select a photo. Taking a photo could use the device's full camera resolution or less depending on settings. Selecting a photo could be *any* size at all and it doesn't have to be local due to Picassa storage, etc. So my app gets a URI back. No way to know what's underneath that URI nor know the size. So what do I set the sampling size to? I can't believe there is no good way to make this happen.

Comment: Changing to RGB_55 and the scaled image did the trick for me. Hope this error does not come back. Thank you for simplifying the Google doc!

Answer (score 42):

Please see this for a guide on loading large Bitmaps more efficiently:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

A 400 KB image file can easily take up 5-10 MB of RAM.

Comment: I still have an OutOfMemoryError with this Google recommendation... Upset.

Answer (score 8):

The size of the file on disk doesn't necessarily coincide with the size of the file in memory.  Chances are likely that the file is compressed, which they won't be when decoded. You need to account for that in your calculation.

Multiply the size of the image (width x height) by the color depth of the image to get the in-memory size of the image.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can resolve your issue by trying to scale your `Bitmap` and you'll see memory consumption reduced. To do it you can copy he method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11785179/828728).

Also, there is a dedicated page at Android Developeres that could help you understand better how to load large Bitmaps. Take a look at the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 1):

While the above answers are obviously correct, a better practice is also to set *explicitly* the ImageView's bitmap/src property to *null*, when they're no longer used, mostly when your activity is being destroyed.
Any other heavy duty resources( large text, audio, video) etc. may also be nullified.
This ensures that the resources are freed instantly, and not wait for the GC to collect.

Comment: Community, could you please provide some feedback at this approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign the bitmap via [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library. Glide uses the most appropriate method (specific to your device and environment) to port the bitmap file into the graphical layer(ImageView).

Nice and easy:

```
Glide.with(getContext())
            .load(imageFile.getPath())
            .into(previewImageView);
```

Answer (score -2):

I resolved **OutOfMemoryError** issue using below method

```
private Bitmap downloadImageBitmap(String sUrl) {
        this.url = sUrl;
        bitmap = null;
                    try {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            for (options.inSampleSize = 1; options.inSampleSize <= 32; options.inSampleSize++) {
                InputStream inputStream = new URL(sUrl).openStream();  
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);      
                    inputStream.close();
                    break;
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError) {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

I change the insample size by 2. My problem is resolved. But be sure that quality of image doesnt get destroy.

Comment: Just changing inSampleSize without knowing what you do, nor explain it, should not be an answer.