# what do we mean by Clamp target GC heap from 55.234MB to 48.000MB?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'm using ImageLoader in one of ma listview to display images from URL. While scrolling the list, app didn't response. I checked logcat and got this log report http://pastebin.com/Zfsk7r9X. In this log, "Clamp target GC heap from 55.234MB to 48.00MB" is shown. How can I avoid this memory issue. I've done System.GC() in ImageLoader class.
decodeFile() which i used is shown below

```
// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {

        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that understanding what the "Clamp target GC heap" message means won't help solve your problem.

Comment: This may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820266/android-bitmapfactory-decodestream-out-of-memory-with-a-400kb-file-with-2mb-f.

Comment: @StephenC Thnx for reply. Then how will i solve this? App force closed in sometimes(like bluemoon)

Comment: @yakshaver Thnx for reply. I saw and tried it. But issues remain. :(

Comment: You solve the problem by following the advice in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820266/android-bitmapfactory-decodestream-out-of-memory-with-a-400kb-file-with-2mb-f ... or getting more memory.  Basically, your app is trying to use too much memory

Answer (score 5):

The message "Clamp target GC heap" is by logged by the VM when it gets desperate, a heap allocation fails, and the heap is returned to a previous ideal limit after the attempt. From documentation of `setIdealFootprint` in HeapSource.cpp:

```
/*
 * Sets the maximum number of bytes that the heap source is allowed
 * to allocate from the system.  Clamps to the appropriate maximum
 * value.
 */
```