# Can't Draw Recycled Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Is this code has any error ? When I run this i got an error here as Can't draw recycled bitmap.
I got this code from while i am reading through stack overflow itself.

```
`Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(urlString,options);
 imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bm);
    if(bm!=null){
        bm.recycle();
    }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only call call recycle() in your Activity's onDestroy(), and only if you know why you need to. Normally it's not necessary, unless you're facing e.g. memory issues. Your current recycle() may be called before the View's onDraw() is called, or there may be other code that triggers a draw call on the View, which would cause the error. So I suggest you remove the recycle() call as a starting point.

Comment: if i didn't recycle bitmap it shows OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: See usage of 'inSampleSize in these examples for how to avoid OOM error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235287/suggestions-to-avoid-bitmap-out-of-memory-error

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
if(bm!=null){
        bm.recycle();
    }`
```

recycle bitmap only if is not used or referred at all anymore.