# App crashes, when using ScrollView

Tags: android

When I using *ScrollView* it works 5 *imagebuttons*, but if I try to add a new one, it crashes with "OutofMemory error", this is weird, because when I re-used the buttons, that's I used before, it worked fine, and I don't know why. The all images are the same resoultion (530x143), with transparent background.

Here's my .xml, I hope you can help me:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cat_ib1"
            android:layout_width="235sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_action" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cat_ib2"
            android:layout_width="235sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cat_ib1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cat_iv_csik"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_adventure" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cat_ib3"
            android:layout_width="235sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cat_ib2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cat_ib1"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_animation" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cat_ib4"
            android:layout_width="235sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cat_ib3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cat_ib2"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_anime" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cat_ib5"
            android:layout_width="235sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cat_ib4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cat_ib3"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_biography" />

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cat_ib6"
        android:layout_width="235sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cat_ib5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cat_ib4"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/categories_cartoon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cat_ib7"
            android:layout_width="235sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cat_ib6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cat_ib5"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_comedy" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cat_ib8"
            android:layout_width="235sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cat_ib7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cat_ib6"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/categories_crime_gangster" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_iv_csik"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/csik" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

After the cat_ib5 button, whenever I try to add an another *ImageButton* the app goes crash.
(The Whole code is in RelativeLayout)

Comment: Try to set the Image source programmaticly and set it through reduced Bitmap, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14235287/7569106) to relate

Comment: Looks like drawable image bit heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your image in @drawable/categories_biography to the drawable xxhdpi folder