# Resize Images for website like amazon

Tags: image-processing, xamarin, resize, imageresizer

I would like to get suggestion from you knowledgeable guys about this topic. If I make a website where there are a lot of images (say 10000) and each image has copies of itself in different sizes, because I need to display different sizes of the same image. It'd be inefficient to store all these images and display as requested. Alternatively how do I do something like websites Amazon, Flipkart, Alibaba does - they resize each image as needed to be displayed. They have only one copy stored. I'd like anyone who knows about this to point me in a direction.
Thanks

Comment: you can store a high resolution copy and then down sample(re-size it for small size), so you will not loose details of images.

Comment: Yes, that is my line of thought but do you know about the best method I can employ to downsample it ?

Comment: i don't have much exposer of xamarin, here[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265686/xamarin-forms-resize-camera-picture] you may find your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you develop a site with Xamarin? Xamarin is for native apps, not websites. Do you mean Mono and Xamarin Studio to build an ASP.NET website? If that´s the case I would take a look at this library: http://imageresizing.net/

Comment: Yes I mean Xamarin Studio, sorry for that. Basically I want to know how amazon, ebay and such other websites do it. Thank you for your help