# Image on button to resize with button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do something which I would think is pretty simple, but I'm having no luck. I have a button that's using an image and when I resize the button, I'd like the image to resize along with it. I've tried HeightRequest and WidthRequest on the button, but it just resizes the button itself, not the image. I also tried putting the button inside a Stack Layout and setting fill and expand, but still no luck. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resize the image, you should use DependencyService to do the resize operation on Android and iOS separately.

Check the following answer that contains an example for such implementation:

[Xamarin Forms - Resize Camera Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265686/xamarin-forms-resize-camera-picture/25268405#25268405)

You can also check the sample project dealing with resizing of an image on Xamarin's offical website:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/XamFormsImageResize/