# How to speed up recyclerview scroll?

Tags: java, android

i have a countdown timer in items recyclerview. this runs every second and change my textview value. this work Causing speed low and lag app on scroll. how can i speed up my recyclerview??

Comment: Try to use your count-down timer in your activity instead of recyclerview adapter, Use broadcast to set text values. if possible then post your code.

Comment: You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40147626/876267).