# I fetch this type of error plase help me

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:58)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:54)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at gonepalguide.igctech.app.FragmentHotel.adapter.EntryHotelAdapter.getView(EntryHotelAdapter.java:96)
at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1638)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820266/android-bitmapfactory-decodestream-out-of-memory-with-a-400kb-file-with-2mb-f

Comment: @Prakash : Please add code and more detail about where you getting this error..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you recycling Bitmap Object.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath);   
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

And recycle by using following code.

```
if(bm!=null){
   bm.recycle();
   bm=null;
}
```

Or use following code in manifest application tag.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

It seems like your image too big. Scale your image before pass to another activity.

```
 Bitmap a = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
  photo = scaleBitmap(a, 200, 150);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);


 public Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,int newWidth,int newHeight) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);

        float ratioX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
        float ratioY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
        float middleX = newWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = newHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, middleX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        return scaledBitmap;

    }
```