# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No request transformation found: XYZ in ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Hey I am working in ktor. I am getting weird issue and I am trying to find the issue, but unable to get the proper reference.

**androidMain**

**AndroidHttpClient.kt**

```
package com.example.kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule

import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.okhttp.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.serialization.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.*
import io.ktor.util.reflect.*
import io.ktor.utils.io.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

actual fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit) = createHttpClient(config)

var converter: KotlinxSerializationConverter? = null

fun createHttpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit): HttpClient {
    val httpClient = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
        config(this)
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.SIMPLE
            level = LogLevel.BODY
        }
        expectSuccess = false
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            converter = KotlinxSerializationConverter(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                explicitNulls = false
            })
        }
        engine {
            config {
                retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            }
        }
        defaultRequest {
            header("Client-Version", Platform().versionCode)
        }
        install(Auth) {
            bearer {
                loadTokens {
                    BearerTokens(tokenProvider.accessToken, "")
                }
                refreshTokens {
                    val response =
                        client.post("https://vivek-modi/api/v1/session/refresh") {
                            markAsRefreshTokenRequest()
                            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                            setBody(KtorSessionCommand(tokenProvider.refreshToken))
                        }
                    if (response.status == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
                        null
                    } else {
                        val ktorLoginResponse = response.body<KtorLoginResponse>()
                        ktorLoginResponse.accessToken?.let { ktorAccessToken ->
                            ktorAccessToken.accessToken?.let { accessToken ->
                                ktorAccessToken.refreshToken?.let { refreshToken ->
                                    BearerTokens(accessToken, refreshToken)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    httpClient.responsePipeline.intercept(HttpResponsePipeline.Transform) { (info, body) ->
        if (body !is ByteReadChannel) return@intercept
        val response = context.response
        val apiResponse = if (response.status.value in 200..299) {
            ApiResponse.Success(
                converter?.deserialize(context.request.headers.suitableCharset(), info.ofInnerClassParameter(), body)
            )
        } else {
            ApiResponse.Error(responseCode = response.status.value)
        }
        proceedWith(HttpResponseContainer(info, apiResponse))
    }
    return httpClient
}

fun TypeInfo.ofInnerClassParameter(): TypeInfo {
    val typeProjection = kotlinType?.arguments?.get(0)
    val kType = typeProjection!!.type!!
    return TypeInfo(kType.classifier as KClass<*>, kType.platformType)
}
```

**Platform.kt**

```
lateinit var provider: VersionAndroidProvider
lateinit var tokenProvider: AndroidToken

actual class Platform actual constructor() {
    actual val versionCode get() = provider.version
}

interface VersionAndroidProvider {
    val version: String
}

interface AndroidToken {
    val accessToken: String
    val refreshToken: String
}
```

**commainMain**

**CommonHttpClient.kt**

```
expect fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit = {}): HttpClient
```

**KtorCountryApi**

```
package com.example.kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule

import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

class KtorCountryApi(private val httpClient: HttpClient) {
    suspend fun getCountry(): ApiResponse<KtorCountriesResponse> {
        return httpClient.get {
            url("https://vivek-modi/api/v1/address/country")
        }.body()
    }
}

@Serializable
data class KtorCountriesResponse(
    val items: List<KtorCountry>? = null
)

@Serializable
data class KtorCountry(
    val id: String? = null,
    val isCurrentCountry: Boolean? = null,
    var isoAlpha2Code: String? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var phonePrefix: String? = null,
    val usesPerAreaShipping: Boolean? = null
)

@Serializable
data class KtorLoginResponse(
    val accessToken: KtorAccessTokenInfo? = null,
)

@Serializable
data class KtorAccessTokenInfo(
    val accessToken: String? = null,
    val refreshToken: String? = null,
    val lastRefreshDateTime: String? = null,
)

@Serializable
data class KtorSessionCommand(
    val refreshToken: String? = null,
)
```

**Error**

```
2022-04-27 17:19:21.633 8417-8417/com.example.app.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app.dev, PID: 8417
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No request transformation found: KtorSessionCommand(refreshToken=abcjks)
        at io.ktor.client.request.HttpRequestBuilder.build(HttpRequest.kt:118)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:130)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:141)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:126)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:81)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceedWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:91)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:125)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invoke(Unknown Source:15)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:123)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:81)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt:35)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invoke(Unknown Source:11)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:123)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:81)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute$ktor_utils(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:101)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:77)
        at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.execute$ktor_client_core(HttpClient.kt:184)
        at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.executeUnsafe(HttpStatement.kt:107)
        at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.execute(HttpStatement.kt:46)
        at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.execute(HttpStatement.kt:61)
        at com.example.kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule.HttpClientKt$createHttpClient$httpClient$1$5$1$2.invokeSuspend(HttpClient.kt:121)
        at com.example.kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule.HttpClientKt$createHttpClient$httpClient$1$5$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.example.kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule.HttpClientKt$createHttpClient$httpClient$1$5$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.BearerAuthProvider$refreshToken$newToken$1.invokeSuspend(BearerAuthProvider.kt:127)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.BearerAuthProvider$refreshToken$newToken$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.BearerAuthProvider$refreshToken$newToken$1.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.AuthTokenHolder.setToken$ktor_client_auth(AuthTokenHolder.kt:47)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.providers.BearerAuthProvider.refreshToken(BearerAuthProvider.kt:126)
        at io.ktor.client.plugins.auth.Auth$Plugin$install$2.invokeSuspend(Auth.kt:61)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:138)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:112)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:14)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:62)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:138)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:112)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:14)
        at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:62)
```

When I am getting 401 in api call then this giving me error. Maybe there is something need to fix in refreshToken logic, but I am not sure what.

**UPDATE**

After **@AlekseiTirman** suggestion I put breakpoint on **HttpCallValidator**, I found this cause

```
Fail to serialize body. Content has type: class com.example.kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule.KtorSessionCommand, but OutgoingContent expected.
If you expect serialized body, please check that you have installed the corresponding plugin(like `ContentNegotiation`) and set `Content-Type` header.
```

[image]

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in the `catch` block in `HttpCallValidator.kt:130` to find out the original exception.

Comment: Are you sure your `URL` is right because there is no domain defined in your URL `https://vivek-modi/api/v1/session/refresh")`?

Comment: @Praveen Url will not work without vpn. Can you please try your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assigned `KotlinxSerializationConverter()` object to the **top-level** `converter` property but didn't register it in the `ContentNegotiation` plugin. You can register a converter for a specific content type with the `register` method:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    converter = KotlinxSerializationConverter(Json {
        prettyPrint = true
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        explicitNulls = false
    })
    register(ContentType.Application.Json, converter!!)
}
```

Comment: Even by doing this, I still get: `TRACE i.k.server.engine.DefaultTransform - No Default Transformations found for class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel 
TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - Skipping response body transformation from String to OutgoingContent for the POST...`.